AWS Data Transfer Free tier limit exceeded earlier than expected
I recently got an AWS account to experiment with EC2 instances. On my EC2 instance, all I did was to install a MATE GUI and a bunch of other packets to support a VNC server. Then I connected from my personal machine over PuTTy + VNC client to have access to my GUI.
However within 24 hours since I opened my accout I got an email notifying me that I already reached the 1 GB AWS Data Transfer Free tier limit. Can someone help me understand what contributed towards this limit?
See screenshot here: Billing and Cost Management > Free Tier
Note: I only spent ~10 mins connected remotely to the GUI and about an hour over ssh installing the packets. I also created then immediately terminated a few (~5) EC2 instances during this time.

Probably billing page can help you to understand your account spending. By expanding Description column you can check "Usage Type" and "Usage Quantity"

Did you use t2.micro instances?

@Vigen - indeed I can see that AWS Data Transfer has reached 1 GB (out of the 1GB free tier limit), but I am not sure how I ended up consuming that limit.

@JustinCarter - I also used some non-free instances and that's ok, the cost for those matches up my expectation. It's onlt the usage of the AWS Data Transfer that I can't explain. I'll update the description with a screenshot of the associated free-tier limit.

Based on the report it's definitely EC2.  Not sure what you should look at past this though.
